# Can not update a table in phpmyadmin with php file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, server

I have this snippet of code in jquery supposed to do something on mouse click.  I want to get a click to activate the php file and update a table in phpmyadmin, but it doesnt work for me.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#ctrl_1").click(function(){
            if ($("#ctrl_1").css("background-color")=="yellow"){
            $("#ctrl_1").css("background-color", "white");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "state="+0,                   
                url: "database.php", 
                success: function(data){
                    $('span').html('off');

                }


            });

            }
            else {
                $("#ctrl_1").css("background-color", "yellow");

                 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data:"state="+ 1,                   
                url: "database.php", 
                success: function(data){
                    $('span').html('on');
                }


            });

            }



        });

    });
```

This is my short php code to connect the server and execute the query :

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'mydatabase';

$var = $_POST['state']; 

mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_database($dbname) or die (mysql_error());




$sql = "UPDATE table SET state=1 WHERE number=1";

mysql_multi_query($sql);
```

The POST variable is not important. I dont want to do anything with it right now.Only execute the query.

**I also get this message on console log:
GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery-1.4.2.min.js:130 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/dani/Desktop/new/new/database.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.**

Comment: can u remove space on this line ...data: "state="+0, too many space for commas, also for data: "state="+1

Comment: Fixed it. Still not working..it's server connecting problem.

Comment: Try open developer console, then see the network tab for ajax request either reach out or not at your server side

Comment: Look like you open the file without web server. Where you open this file? From folder or using web server like xampp, wampp??

Comment: I open the html file that connect to the js file in my web browser..

Comment: this is your php file located file:///C:/Users/daskalo/Desktop/smart_office_stub_code_short/smart_office_stub_code_short/database.php. This file must be run on web server. You can't open directly from folder itselt.

Comment: how I do it with phpmyadmin?

Comment: Right now i'm assuming you open the file directly without web server. Suppose you already installed web server package like xampp, then put your project folder into htdocs, and open file using web browser. Then see what happen next.

Comment: OK.  What file I need to open? I have html, js and php files, all connected. I know I should open html with web browser, dont understand what to do with the others. I have wampServer installed on my computer.

Comment: Do you ever run php file before??

Comment: yes..not with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to web programming..

Comment: how you open php file before??

Comment: I connected ftp:// host/ in my computer...ant put this file in public_html folder

Comment: then, in web browser, how you access those file. What your url look like while accessing.

Answer (score 3):

This error means that you should not source jquery with such link:

```
file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

nor with such:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

but by http:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: and how I do it? I have this line in my html:

Comment: <script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>